# Can I create alternative brackets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to have a larger range of brackets. To give an idea, I can already modify the normal square bracket:

```
class City
 def initialize(city:)
   @city = city
 end

 def [](man) 
   print "I am #{man} of #{city}"
 end 
end
```

So I can do:

```
paris = City.new city: "Paris"
paris["George"] # ==> I am George of Paris
```

But now I would like to add new brackets like this:

```
class City
 def initialize(city:)
  @city = city
 end

 def [M M](man) 
   print "I am man: #{man} of #{city}"
 end 

 def [W W](woman) 
   print "I am woman: #{woman} of #{city}"
 end
end
```

So I can do something like this:

```
paris = City.new city: "Paris"
paris[M "George" M] # ==> I am man: George of Paris
paris[W "Lisa" W]  # ==> I am woman: Lisa of Paris
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: No this is not possible. `[]` is a method, not a magic.

Comment: You should not use square brackets for this anyway. Square brackets are for indexing an object, for example retrieving an element from an array. Just use a regular method: `paris.say("George", :man) # I am man: George of Paris`

Comment: Of course Devon, that was only an example to make clear the idea. My question is made only to understand the elasticity of Ruby.

Comment: @DevonParsons, I would be liberal in what he can use in Ruby. But you are right that square brackets are a rare resource and one should think twice what useful functionality will ze use it for.

Comment: Sounds like you would need a custom DSL `on top of` ruby

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it, but like the other stated you shouldn't do it.

```
class City
   def initialize(city:)
      @city = city
   end

   def [](type, name) 
     if type == :m
        print "I am man: #{name} of #{city}"
     else
       print "I am woman: #{name} of #{city}"
     end
   end 
end

city = City.new('Paris')
city[:m, 'George']
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally do this with parametrized subclassing. You first create a `Human` class representing people in general, and then you tell each city to include a parametrized subclass of `Human` (`London.Citizen`, `Dublin.citizen`). I will use `YSupport` gem (`gem install y_support`) in these examples to keep the code short, but you can achieve this behavior easily with plain Ruby, too.

```
require 'y_support/all'

class Human
  ★ NameMagic
  selector :sex
  def self.male; new :m end
  def self.female; new :f end
  def initialize sex; @sex = sex end
end

class City
  ★ NameMagic
  delegate :male, :female, to: "self.Citizen"
  def initialize
    param_class( { Citizen: Human }, with: { city: self } )
    class << self.Citizen
      def introduce_self
        "I am a #{{m: :man, f: :woman}[sex]} from #{city}."
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Note `param_class` method that creates a parametrized subclass of `Human` for every city, representing a citizen of that city:

```
London, Paris = City.new, City.new
Tom = London.male
Lisa = Paris.female
```